# JSON parse error: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException [Spring Boot - Feign Client]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

When I make a request to a service containing java.util.Date with feignclient, I get this error "`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1692738000000' could not be parsed at index 0`"

**My dto;**

```
public class InputDto {
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
}
```

**FeignClient service;**

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/searchFile"}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse<List<FileDto>>> searchFile(@RequestBody InputDto searchDto);
```

If I define my variables as **java.time.LocalDate** I don't get an error. why does this problem occur?

Comment: Which is the underlying json library?

Comment: And not really related but try to move away from `java.util.Date` and use the modern `java.time` API

Comment: @Chaosfire I use "com.fasterxml.jackson"  version: 2.13.4

Comment: I'm wondering what is the cause of this problem.

Comment: It's error prone and misleading. A `Date` is not a date, it's actually an instant since the epoch, it has no concept of timezone, despite that it's `toString()` makes it look like that, and so on. That's why people were using `joda.time`, instead of it, before java 8 introduced `java.time`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, jackson successfully deserializes the timestamp to a date for me. Maybe share jackson's configuration along with the payload.

Comment: *And not really related ...* @Chaosfire I hope it *is* related. Moving away from the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` classwould be a good part of a solution if not *the* solution.

Comment: @OleV.V. I totally agree, moving away from `Date` is always for the best. It's just that the question is specifically about it and we don't know if using `java.time` is an option for OP.

Answer (score 0):

### Why does this problem occur?

The issue occurs because of the differences in how Java's `Date` class and the newer `java.time.LocalDate` class are serialized and deserialized when working with JSON libraries like FeignClient.

When you use the `java.time.LocalDate` class, you're using a more modern date representation that aligns well with ISO-8601 date formats, which are widely recognized and supported in JSON serialization libraries. `LocalDate` is designed to work seamlessly with JSON serialization, which is why you're not encountering any errors.

The error you initially encountered, `"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1692738000000' could not be parsed at index 0"`, suggests that the value `'1692738000000'` is not recognized as a valid date string by the default parsing logic for the `Date` class. JSON serialization libraries expect date strings to be in a specific format, and when the value doesn't conform to that format, parsing errors occur.

### Solution

In my opinion a good solution is **customize date serialization**, this way:

First, create a custom serializer for the `Date` class that formats dates as strings in a specific format. In this example, I'll use the ISO-8601 date format:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(dateFormat.format(value));
    }
}
```

Next, create a custom deserializer for the `Date` class that parses date strings in the same format:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String dateString = p.getText();
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IOException("Error parsing date: " + dateString, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, annotate your `Date` fields in the `InputDto` class with the custom serializers and deserializers:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

public class InputDto {
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    private Date startDate;

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    private Date endDate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: So what is causing this problem? Why should I do such a customization?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, I improved my answer.